# Unfortunately <appname> has stopped

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, andengine

I have seen many similar questions to this one posted on SO but none seem to answer my question. Quite simply, every time I try and run my app on the emulator, it quits back to the main menu and displays a dialog saying "Unfortunatley, Scribble Runner has stopped". Here is my `BaseActivity` class and my `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

BaseActivity:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.andengine.engine.camera.Camera;
import org.andengine.engine.options.EngineOptions;
import org.andengine.engine.options.ScreenOrientation;
import org.andengine.engine.options.resolutionpolicy.RatioResolutionPolicy;
import org.andengine.entity.scene.Scene;
import org.andengine.entity.sprite.Sprite;
import org.andengine.entity.util.FPSLogger;
import org.andengine.opengl.font.Font;
import org.andengine.opengl.font.FontFactory;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.ITexture;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.BitmapTextureAtlas;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.bitmap.BitmapTexture;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.region.ITextureRegion;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.region.TextureRegion;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.region.TextureRegionFactory;
import org.andengine.ui.activity.SimpleBaseGameActivity;
import org.andengine.util.adt.io.in.IInputStreamOpener;
import org.andengine.util.debug.Debug;

import android.util.Log;


public class BaseActivity extends SimpleBaseGameActivity {

    //CONSTANTS AND FIELDS
    public static int CAMERA_WIDTH = 720;
    public static int CAMERA_HEIGHT = 480;

    public Font mFont;
    public Camera mCamera;
    private ITextureRegion mBackgroundTextureRegion, mEnemyTextureRegion;
    private BitmapTextureAtlas mAutoParallaxBackgroundTexture;
    private TextureRegion mParallaxLayerFront;
    private TextureRegion mParallaxLayerMid;
    private TextureRegion mParallaxLayerBack;


    public Scene mCurrentScene;
    public static BaseActivity instance;


    @Override
    public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {
        instance = this;
        mCamera = new Camera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);
        System.out.println("Engine Created");
        return new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_SENSOR, new
                RatioResolutionPolicy(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT), mCamera);

    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreateResources() {

        BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.setAssetBasePath("gfx/");
        try{
        this.mAutoParallaxBackgroundTexture = new BitmapTextureAtlas(this.getTextureManager(), 1024, 1024);
        this.mParallaxLayerFront = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(this.mAutoParallaxBackgroundTexture, this, "parallax_background_layer_front.png", 0, 0);
        this.mParallaxLayerBack = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(this.mAutoParallaxBackgroundTexture, this, "parallax_background_layer_back.png", 0, 188);
        this.mParallaxLayerMid = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(this.mAutoParallaxBackgroundTexture, this, "parallax_background_layer_mid.png", 0, 669);
        this.mAutoParallaxBackgroundTexture.load();
        System.out.println("Resources Created");
        }catch(Exception e){
            Debug.e(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Scene onCreateScene() {
        mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new FPSLogger());
        mCurrentScene = new Scene();
        Sprite backgroundSprite1 = new Sprite(0, 0, this.mParallaxLayerBack, getVertexBufferObjectManager());
        Sprite backgroundSprite2 = new Sprite(0, 0, this.mParallaxLayerMid, getVertexBufferObjectManager());
        Sprite backgroundSprite3 = new Sprite(0, 0, this.mParallaxLayerFront, getVertexBufferObjectManager());
        mCurrentScene.attachChild(backgroundSprite1);
        mCurrentScene.attachChild(backgroundSprite2);
        mCurrentScene.attachChild(backgroundSprite3);
        System.out.println("Scene Created");
        return mCurrentScene;
    }

    public static BaseActivity getSharedInstance(){
        return instance;
    }

    //change the current main scene
    public void setCurrentScene(Scene scene){
        mCurrentScene = scene;
        getEngine().setScene(mCurrentScene);
    }

}
```

Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.provisionalsolutions.scribblerunner"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.provisionalsolutions.scribblerunner.BaseActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

And here is the LogCat:

```
02-06 13:41:21.664: W/ActivityManager(275): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.android.email.ACCOUNT_INTENT } U=0: not found
02-06 13:41:21.674: W/Trace(589): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-06 13:41:21.697: E/ActivityThread(589): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cf2458 that was originally bound here
02-06 13:41:21.697: E/ActivityThread(589): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cf2458 that was originally bound here
02-06 13:41:21.697: E/ActivityThread(589):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
02-06 13:41:21.697: E/ActivityThread(589):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
02-06 13:41:21.697: E/ActivityThread(589):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
02-06 13:41:21.697: E/ActivityThread(589):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
02-06 13:41:21.697: E/ActivityThread(589):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
02-06 13:41:21.697: E/ActivityThread(589):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
02-06 13:41:21.697: E/ActivityThread(589):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
02-06 13:41:21.697: E/ActivityThread(589):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
02-06 13:41:21.697: E/ActivityThread(589):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
02-06 13:41:21.697: E/ActivityThread(589):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
02-06 13:41:21.697: E/ActivityThread(589):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
02-06 13:41:21.697: E/ActivityThread(589):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
02-06 13:41:21.697: E/ActivityThread(589):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
02-06 13:41:21.697: E/ActivityThread(589):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
02-06 13:41:21.697: E/ActivityThread(589):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
02-06 13:41:21.697: E/ActivityThread(589):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
02-06 13:41:21.697: E/ActivityThread(589):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
02-06 13:41:21.714: E/StrictMode(589): null
02-06 13:41:21.714: E/StrictMode(589): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cf2458 that was originally bound here
02-06 13:41:21.714: E/StrictMode(589):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
02-06 13:41:21.714: E/StrictMode(589):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
02-06 13:41:21.714: E/StrictMode(589):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
02-06 13:41:21.714: E/StrictMode(589):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
02-06 13:41:21.714: E/StrictMode(589):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
02-06 13:41:21.714: E/StrictMode(589):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
02-06 13:41:21.714: E/StrictMode(589):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
02-06 13:41:21.714: E/StrictMode(589):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
02-06 13:41:21.714: E/StrictMode(589):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
02-06 13:41:21.714: E/StrictMode(589):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
02-06 13:41:21.714: E/StrictMode(589):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
02-06 13:41:21.714: E/StrictMode(589):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
02-06 13:41:21.714: E/StrictMode(589):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
02-06 13:41:21.714: E/StrictMode(589):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
02-06 13:41:21.714: E/StrictMode(589):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
02-06 13:41:21.714: E/StrictMode(589):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
02-06 13:41:21.714: E/StrictMode(589):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
02-06 13:41:21.714: W/ActivityManager(275): Unbind failed: could not find connection for android.os.BinderProxy@40e80c68
02-06 13:41:21.724: E/ActivityThread(589): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d19e88 that was originally bound here
02-06 13:41:21.724: E/ActivityThread(589): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d19e88 that was originally bound here
02-06 13:41:21.724: E/ActivityThread(589):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
02-06 13:41:21.724: E/ActivityThread(589):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
02-06 13:41:21.724: E/ActivityThread(589):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
02-06 13:41:21.724: E/ActivityThread(589):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
02-06 13:41:21.724: E/ActivityThread(589):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
02-06 13:41:21.724: E/ActivityThread(589):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
02-06 13:41:21.724: E/ActivityThread(589):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
02-06 13:41:21.724: E/ActivityThread(589):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
02-06 13:41:21.724: E/ActivityThread(589):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
02-06 13:41:21.724: E/ActivityThread(589):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
02-06 13:41:21.724: E/ActivityThread(589):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
02-06 13:41:21.724: E/ActivityThread(589):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
02-06 13:41:21.724: E/ActivityThread(589):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
02-06 13:41:21.724: E/ActivityThread(589):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
02-06 13:41:21.724: E/ActivityThread(589):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
02-06 13:41:21.724: E/ActivityThread(589):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
02-06 13:41:21.734: E/StrictMode(589): null
02-06 13:41:21.734: E/StrictMode(589): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d19e88 that was originally bound here
02-06 13:41:21.734: E/StrictMode(589):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
02-06 13:41:21.734: E/StrictMode(589):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
02-06 13:41:21.734: E/StrictMode(589):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
02-06 13:41:21.734: E/StrictMode(589):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
02-06 13:41:21.734: E/StrictMode(589):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
02-06 13:41:21.734: E/StrictMode(589):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
02-06 13:41:21.734: E/StrictMode(589):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
02-06 13:41:21.734: E/StrictMode(589):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
02-06 13:41:21.734: E/StrictMode(589):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
02-06 13:41:21.734: E/StrictMode(589):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
02-06 13:41:21.734: E/StrictMode(589):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
02-06 13:41:21.734: E/StrictMode(589):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
02-06 13:41:21.734: E/StrictMode(589):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
02-06 13:41:21.734: E/StrictMode(589):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
02-06 13:41:21.734: E/StrictMode(589):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
02-06 13:41:21.734: E/StrictMode(589):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

here is another part of the stack trace showing errors:

```
    02-06 13:45:37.300: E/AndroidRuntime(815): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-06 13:45:37.300: E/AndroidRuntime(815): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.provisionalsolutions.scribblerunner/com.provisionalsolutions.scribblerunner.BaseActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.provisionalsolutions.scribblerunner.BaseActivity" on path: /data/app/com.provisionalsolutions.scribblerunner-2.apk
02-06 13:45:37.300: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
02-06 13:45:37.300: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
02-06 13:45:37.300: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
02-06 13:45:37.300: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
02-06 13:45:37.300: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-06 13:45:37.300: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-06 13:45:37.300: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
02-06 13:45:37.300: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-06 13:45:37.300: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-06 13:45:37.300: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-06 13:45:37.300: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
02-06 13:45:37.300: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-06 13:45:37.300: E/AndroidRuntime(815): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.provisionalsolutions.scribblerunner.BaseActivity" on path: /data/app/com.provisionalsolutions.scribblerunner-2.apk
02-06 13:45:37.300: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
02-06 13:45:37.300: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
02-06 13:45:37.300: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
02-06 13:45:37.300: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
02-06 13:45:37.300: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
02-06 13:45:37.300: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: I may be missing something, but I cannot see the code you're displaying being involved in any way with the stack trace displayed.

Comment: I ahve posted the parts of the stack trace that were showing errors...most of the other traces are just rubbish but i can post them if required?

Comment: Do you have any stack trace that involves your displayed code (ie containing a reference to at least one of the functions in `BaseActivity`?)

Comment: as mentioned by @Ekonion, the stack points to something related to intents and there are no intents on your source code. Do you have more code somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
02-06 13:41:21.664: W/ActivityManager(275): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.android.email.ACCOUNT_INTENT } U=0: not found
02-06 13:41:21.674: W/Trace(589): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
```

this tells you, you have a problem with an intent... in your posted code is no intent, so i think the problem belongs to another part of your program ^^

Comment: I have posted more errors from the stack trace which I think are more relevant...

Comment: the new errorlog tells you, that your calss is not available in the path you gave the programm... either you made a tipping-mistake, or the class is anywhere else, tahn it should be.`{com.provisionalsolutions.scribblerunner/com.provisionalsolutions.scribblerunner.BaseActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class ` shows this

Comment: do you have any ideas on how to solve this? I'm not sure how is was caused in the first place

Comment: first of all check if your source is there, where it is mentioned in the erorrlog, if it is, look if you had any tipping mistakes made, if this doesnt solve it too, its the easiest (my oopinion) tocreate a new project and rename what is missing (did this several times already and always worked) Of course you copy all your code ^^

Comment: Creating a new project and copying the code in has worked! seems like just another android-eclipse bug. Many thanks